# Elasticsearch rails re-index a particular model in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

How to re-index a particular model in production mode in elasticsearch-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command from terminal

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='Article'
```